# Check the box conditionally upon page load using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Upon page load all of the check boxes remain unchecked (pic below), I'm getting value1 text from java session and storing it under JSON object, now I'm comparing if the value1 text of the below page matches with value1 text I'm getting from session. If match found then make the check box true else keep it unchecked. I'm trying below, but it checks all the boxes..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $.s1.proxy.contentReady(function() {
                var sessionValue = <%= json %>;  //loaded from java session
                sessionValue.forEach(function(sessionValue) {
                         $("input:checkbox[name=myFormProperties]").each(function(){      
                            var val = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2)").text().trim();
                             if(val!=null && val!=''){
                                 if (sessionValue.startsWith(val)) {
                                    alert("session and page value match found ");
                                     $("input:checkbox[name=myFormProperties]").attr('checked', true); // this makes all the checkbox value true. How to make only //specific check box value true here
                                }
                             }
                        });
                    });
            });

        </script>
```

Upon check box true that selected value come as a link next to the check box as shown in pic. 
[image: Check Boxes]

Comment: You can use `$(this).attr('checked', true);` instead of `$("input:checkbox[name=myFormProperties]").attr('checked', true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are setting it on all the checkboxes with name myFormProperties.

Instead of                                      `$("input:checkbox[name=myFormProperties]").attr('checked', true);` (which just selects all the checkboxes again), just select the current checkbox from the each loop like this

```
$(this).attr('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making all the check box checked with your code

```
$("input:checkbox[name=myFormProperties]").attr('checked', true);
```

For checking the checkbox with value use below

```
$("input[value='" + val + "']").prop('checked', true);
```